# lucidabr installation difficulties: ! "I can't find file `hlcrima'."

Tags: fonts, lucida

I've just bought the Lucida open type fonts from TUG. I'm on Mac OS 10.8, and I've installed the actual fonts using "Font Book".  I have downloaded `lucidabr.zip` and `lucidaot.zip` from CTAN and unzipped them in my `texmf/tex/latex` directory.  I ran LaTeX on `lucidabr.ins`.  But when I run LaTeX on the MWE in the Lucida installation instructions, I get all sorts of error messages, and no output.

This is the mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[altbullet]{lucidabr}
\begin{document}
   Here's some text. And here's some math:
\[
\phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{-x^{2}/2}
\]
Euro, copyright, and bullet symbols are available:
\texteuro \textcopyright \textbullet.
\end{document}
```

This is the first error message:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexmf hlcrima
! I can't find file `hlcrima'.
<*> ...=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input hlcrima
```

I get similar error messages for `hlcry` and `hlcrv`.

What do I need to do to get things working?

Comment: The `hlcrcima` font refers to the Type1 font distribution. For the OpenType fonts you should choose the fonts with `fontspec`.

Comment: @egreg I don't know how to do that.

Comment: For the Type 1 version you have to run `updmap-sys --enable Map=lumath-k.map` and maybe also `updmap-sys --enable Map=lucidabr-k.map`. The files are part of the Lucida fonts and are in `fonts/map/dvips/`

Comment: @Herbert I'm using the OpenType fonts.  Should I still run those same commands?

Comment: No, then you have to use package `unicode-math` and then `\setmainfont{Lucida...}` and `\setmathfont{Lucida...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenType Lucida fonts are only usable with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Compile the following with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Scale=.83,Numbers=OldStyle]{Lucida Bright OT}
\setsansfont[Scale=.83]{Lucida Sans OT}
\setmonofont[Scale=.83]{Lucida Sans Typewriter OT}

\begin{document}

\textsf{Sans serif title}

This text is in Lucida Bright. And this is
\texttt{monospaced}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also have the math fonts, the same:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[Scale=.83,Numbers=OldStyle]{Lucida Bright OT}
\setsansfont[Scale=.83]{Lucida Sans OT}
\setmonofont[Scale=.83]{Lucida Sans Typewriter OT}
\setmathfont[Scale=.83]{Lucida Bright Math OT}

\begin{document}

\textsf{Sans serif title}

This text is in Lucida Bright. And this is
\texttt{monospaced}.
\[
\phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{-x^{2}/2}
\]
Euro, copyright, and bullet symbols are available:
\texteuro \textcopyright \textbullet.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I use the type1 fonts with pdfLaTeX?

Comment: @Ruby No, if you didn't buy them from PCTeX (I got them some years ago as a present from Lance Carnes).